# Volatility Framework 2.4 - No suitable address space mapping found

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I made some dumps with different formats (.DMP and some file made by LiveKD utility) in Windows 8.1 x64 OS. The first one is a explorer.exe dump file which was created by TaskManager->Create Dump File function and the other one is the whole system dump(I mean win 8.1) which is about 2.5 GB. While I was trying to use different profiles, I was getting the same error 'No suitable address space mapping found'. As you see, I used 2 different dump files and got the same error message. What I do wrong ?

P.S. I used Kali Linux iso image which was run at VMware player 6.0.5 (Evaluation License). Of course, I tried to ask at official forum, but my acc has not activated yet .___.